# Referring MySQL ENUM in another table

Tags: mysql, enums, constraints

I have a table SkillLevel created as

```
CREATE TABLE `sklllevel` (
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `level` enum('No Experience','Beginner','Expert','Advisor') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With Values

```
INSERT INTO test.sklllevel (name,level) values ('No Experience','No Experience'),('Beginner','Beginner'),('Expert','Expert'),('Advisor','Advisor');
```

I want to refer SkillLevel.Level with `testSkill.tkSkill` in another table created as:

```
CREATE TABLE `testskill` (
  `pkid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tkSkill` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

DO I need to have tkSkill as ENUM with same set of Values to set a foreign key? What is the best practise here?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: enums are stored as a number, so technically, you could join them with `tkSkill` as a tinyint.

To use it as a foreign key, you indeed need to have both `tkSkill` and `level` to be the same enum - but you need `level` to be a `unique` column to qualify as a foreign key, so add `unique` to it (to be really precise: for InnoDB, you can have non-unique foreign keys if you manually create the index, but non-unique foreign keys are generally a bad idea). But you should think about what your key in `sklllevel` should be, since now it looks as if you want `Name` to be the key.

And independently from having it as key you should define `tkSkill` as (the same) enum to make sure they both mean the same if you at one point would like to change the enums (what is a bad idea!) and e.g. add another skilllevel; or if you want to "read" (directly understand) the value when you select directly from the table `testskill` without the need to join `sklllevel`; and if you want to insert values into tkSkill by using their enum-namoe (e.g. 'Expert' instead of 3, but you can use both) without looking them up in `sklllevel`.

Longer answer: Best practice is: don't use enums. Depending on "belief", there is none to only a handful of cases when enums might be slightly useful, if at all. One could be that you don't want to use a reference table to skip a join to display the textvalue/description of an integer-id. In your setup, you are actually using a reference table and still want to use enums.

The closest you'll get to best practice using enums would be to define `tkSkill` as enum in `testskill` and don't have the `sklllevel`-table (the reference table) at all.

But again, I would urge you not to use enums. You can define your table as

```
CREATE TABLE `sklllevel` (
  `Id` tinyint(4) primary key,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and then use that id as a foreign key for `tkSkill`. Or even

```
CREATE TABLE `sklllevel` (
  `Name` varchar(20) primary key
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and then define `tkSkill` as `varchar(20)` and use this as a foreign key - it will use more space, though, but you will have "readable" values in the table if that was the reason for you to use enums in the first place.

Here you can find some background to enums: [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)